# Validate REST filter parameters

Tags: java

I have a GET REST API with some filter parameters. Following are the only valid filter combination:

```
 1. id==123412
 2. name==MyName&age==30
 3. name==MyName&pincode=12345
```

So, following are invalid filter combination:

```
 1. id==123412&name==MyName
 2. name==MyName&age==30&name==MyName
 3. age==30&pincode=12345
 4. pincode=12345
```

However following is a valid combination:

```
age==30&name==MyName
```

I needed some help in validating the above. One approach I had was:

- First to make 3 list having parameter names of the valid combinations
  Like: 
  List1 = {"id"}
  List2 = {"name","age"}
  List3 = {"name","pincode"}
- Then take the parameter names from the input, and check if they match
  any one of the list (But this will further need list sorting and
  compare, because though I do not care about the order of the parameters, I will need to check for duplicates)

Any better way?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any framework? Can you give some more light on the used tools to build up your rest application.

Comment: You should provide clients with all URIs that a client should use to interact with your API. These URIs should have the correct amount and order of filter parameters. This does not mean that you shouldn't validate them on the server side, though I'd rather ignore any unwanted parameters than raise an error therefore.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Spring. But I will need to do the above validation in Java, in my server side logic, as it is the only part that I can make changes in... How should I proceed in this case?